# Horror story compilation, including a story about a child who looked out his window at night and saw a creature that had eyes like car headlights

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, anthology-book

I am trying to find a story compilation from the late '70s or early '80s.

The only story I can remember is about a child who looked out his window at night and saw a creature in the (bog , forest, swamp, back yard?) that had eyes like car headlights but smelled of overpowering garbage. The child tells no one and eventually gets dragged away by the creature.

It was part of a compilation and I would really like to find it again.

Comment: Was it aimed at kids or adults? That will help narrow down the likely anthologies.

Comment: Also, where did you read it? And in what language?

Comment: Language was English - I believe it was a young readers anthology. And Im thinking it was 70s to early 80s because I read it as a youth .